# Phrases using the Arabic particle "al" as a separate word apart from "Al Qaeda" and "Al Jazeera"

Tags: phrases, loanwords

Many words incorporated into English a long time ago have the Arabic particle "al" incorporated into them. For example, "algebra" and "alcohol".

But does English have commonly used phrases with the Arabic particle "al" as a separate word apart from "Al Qaeda" and "Al Jazeera"? I can think of "El Alamein" (why is it "El"?) and [Al-Shabaab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Al-Shabaab_(militant_group)), but nothing else.

I tried looking for Wiktionary's entry on "al" to see if there's a list of compounds formed from it, but the only info it had was under the non-Latin version [ال](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D8%A7%D9%84) and therefore doesn't have a list of English phrases using it.

Comment: You can see an entire list by going to a dictionary and simply looking up "al" with a space after it. After you get through all of the "al" + *space* words, then come the "al" plus hyphen words.  After that, come all of the words that start "al."

Comment: I don't think English has _any_ words that start with 'al ' alone. (OED confirms this). Your examples are all proper names from Arabic with the definite article 'Al' or 'El'.

Comment: Also, wiktionary is crap.

Answer (score 2):

Al is the definite article in Arabic language. In our Egyptian colloquial dialect, we tend to pronounce it as El. I do not know about other dialects.  So Al is the standerd Arabic and El is the daily language.

Comment: This is not really an answer to the OP but more of a very useful comment

Comment: It does answer one part of the question: "...from "Al Qaeda" and "Al Jazeera"...El Alamein" (***why is it "El"?***)...

Comment: I do not know the answer just tried to help explain a point.

Answer (score -1):

There are phrases like *al fresco* and *al dente*, but of course those are Italian not Arabic; what exactly is your interest?

Comment: You should make this a comment

Comment: @Mitch The part before the semicolon answers the question in the OP's 2nd paragraph.